# Ignoring rows and specific output

Tags: vba, row

I am relative new to vba.

I am trying to get this code to work.

```
Sub EksportAsCSV_DK()
Const Delim As String = ";"            'afgrænser (delimiter)
Dim strFileName As String
Dim rngOmr As Range
Dim y As Long                    'tæller
Dim x As Long                    'tæller
Dim strTemp As String                  'streng til de enkelte rækker
Dim lRows As Long                    'antal rækker
Dim lCols As Long                    'antal kolonner
Dim lFno As Long                    'fil nummer

Sheets("in").Select
Range("A1:Q24").Select
strFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="CSV-Fil(*.csv), *.csv")
Set rngOmr = Selection.CurrentRegion
lFno = FreeFile
lRows = rngOmr.Rows.Count
lCols = rngOmr.Columns.Count
Open strFileName For Output As #lFno

For x = 1 To lRows
    strTemp = ""
       For y = 1 To lCols
          strTemp = strTemp & rngOmr(x, y).Text
          If y < lCols Then
             strTemp = strTemp & Delim
          Else
             Print #lFno, strTemp
          End If
       Next

   Next
   Close #lFno
  
   Sheets("User page").Select

End Sub
```

The major problem is, that from A1 to Q17 is locked for the machines software. Row 2 is blank, and maybe because of that it ignores anything from row 2 and up to row 24, which is the maximum I need.

I also want the sheet named "in" in saved CSV file.

Comment: No, it does not make sense. You are not telling us what you try to achieve. What does "locked for the machine software" mean?

Answer (score -1):

You are correct that the count you are using for lRows is returning 1 rather than 24 because of the blank row. Given that you are fixing the range by stating A!:Q24 lRows doesn't need to be dynamic it should always be 24, so you could change it to lRows = 24.  Alternatively if the range in your code is going to be changed to a dynamic range later you could use a different method to find the last row number.  If I have gaps in my data (assuming I'm in ColumnA) I usually  use:

```
Range("A1048576").select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
lRows = ActiveCell.Row
```

An alternative would be to use specialcells(last cell) I'd generally record something like that and then edit it.

For saving as a csv file:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\stuar\Documents\in.csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False`
```

`